# Creating a command to fill a template table

Tags: tables, macros

I'm creating a style file for deliverables for a project. During the draft stage, deliverables need to have a revision history in a table (version, date, modifications, modified by).

In the style file, I define a command:

```
\newcommand{\makedeliverable}{ % very long template
}
```

In any deliverable made using the template, <strike>`\newdeliverable`</strike> `\makedeliverable` is used immediately after `\begin{document}` to create the cover page, table of contents, list of figures etc. (I appreciate this might not be the best way, but it works well and I was able to produce it quickly).

I'd also like this command to create the revision history table, based on revisions specified by a user in their own preamble.

So in the `.sty` file (as part of the `\makedeliverable` command} I would have:

```
\begin{tabular}{|p{0.2\textwidth} | p{0.3\textwidth} | p{0.3\textwidth} | p{0.2\textwidth} |}
    \hline
   \textbf{Version} & \textbf{Date} & \textbf{Modifications} &     \textbf{Modified by}\\
\hline
% something here to populate the table
\end{tabular}
```

And also a command definition along the lines of:

```
\newcommand{\addrevision}[4]{ %something
}
```

Which would be called in the preamble with (e.g.):

```
\addrevision{0.1, 2017-11-27, Added new stuff, J. Bloggs}
\addrevision{0.2, 2017-11-27, Added more new stuff, B. Smith}
```

With my programming hat on, I'd have `\addrevision` populate an array which is then printed out in the table. But I'm unsure how to go about this in LaTeX.

Any advice will be welcome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code below does what I think you want. It uses [LaTeX3](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/l3kernel) to build up a token list for the revision history. The code assumes that the `\addrevision{...}` lines are added in "revision order". Following the recommendations in the [booktabs](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) manual, I have dropped the vertical rules as the general opinion is that tables look better without them (and it is trivial to add them back if they are required).

The code defines two commands:

- `\addrevision{...}`: this accepts/expects a comma separated list of the *four* pieces of "revision data": version, date, modifications, modifier
- `\RevisionHistory`: inserts the current revision history

Here is the output:

[image]

...and here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l_revisions_tl% to hold revision history
\newcommand\addrevision[1]{% add to \l_revisions_tl
  \regex_split:nnN {\,} {#1} \l_tmpa_seq% split #1 on commas
  \seq_pop_left:NN \l_tmpa_seq \l_tmpa_tl% don't want & before first entry
  \tl_put_right:NV \l_revisions_tl \l_tmpa_tl
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { \tl_put_right:Nn \l_revisions_tl {&##1} }
  \tl_put_right:Nn \l_revisions_tl {\\}% add \\ for end of line
}
\newcommand\RevisionHistory{%
  \begin{tabular}{p{0.2\textwidth}p{0.3\textwidth}p{0.3\textwidth}p{0.2\textwidth}}
     \toprule
     \textbf{Version} & \textbf{Date} & \textbf{Modifications} & \textbf{Modified~by}\\
     \midrule
     \tl_use:N \l_revisions_tl
     \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

  \addrevision{0.1, 2017-11-27, Added new stuff, J. Bloggs}
  \addrevision{0.2, 2017-11-27, Added more new stuff, B. Smith}

  \RevisionHistory

\end{document}
```

I have used the same columns widths as in the OP but, probably, columns 1,2 and 4 should all be narrowed and the modifications column should be wider. If the revision history goes on for pages then something like [longtable](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/longtable) or [supertabular](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/supertabular) should be used.

**EDIT**

Here is a second version using `expl3` sequences. This is closer in spirit to the approach suggested in the OP and the code is shorter and, arguably, easier to understand.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \l_revisions_seq
\newcommand\addrevision[1]{% add to \l_revisions_seq
  \seq_put_right:Nn \l_revisions_seq {#1}
}
\newcommand\RevisionHistory{%
\begin{tabular}{p{0.2\textwidth}p{0.3\textwidth}p{0.3\textwidth}p{0.2\textwidth}}
     \toprule
     \textbf{Version} & \textbf{Date} & \textbf{Modifications} & \textbf{Modified~by}\\
     \midrule
     \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_revisions_seq {% loop over revisions
       \regex_split:nnN {\,} {##1} \l_tmpa_seq% split on commas
       \seq_use:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {&}% print the table row
       \\
     }
     \\[-12pt]% \\ is necessary here but it inserts a blank line, so hack...
     \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

  \addrevision{0.1, 2017-11-27, Added new stuff, J. Bloggs}
  \addrevision{0.2, 2017-11-27, Added more new stuff, B. Smith}

  \RevisionHistory

\end{document}
```

For reasons I don't understand, I have had to use the hack `\\[-12pt]\bottomrule` to prevent a blank line from appearing at the bottom of the table. The output is the same as before

Comment: +1, but you `\usepackage{xparse}` and code `\newcommand`?

Comment: No, that's not what I meant, I just thought that including it without actually using it is a bit pointless, but your code is alright. Maybe the l3 guys would point out that this would be one more step towards the separation of code and document level, but I'm not really sure, whether this is necessary here.

Comment: No, LaTeX3 is loaded by `expl3`, which is loaded by `xparse`. `xparse` itself only provides the layers like `\NewDocumentCommand` etc. on top.

Comment: The first method given in this solution worked perfectly! Thanks very much.

Answer (score 5):

The mandatory `\xintFor` solution.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xinttools}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\newcommand\Revisions {}%

\newcommand\addrevision[1]{% 
% append a new revision, the csv list being converted to braced items
    \global\oodef\Revisions
% oodef = twice expand contents, second expansion will expand \Revisions
% itself; first expansion propagates to \xintcsvtolist to convert #1
% into braced items, which we will use with \xintListWithSep later on
    {\expandafter\Revisions\expandafter{\romannumeral0\xintcsvtolist{#1}}}%
}

\newcommand\RevisionHistory{%
  \begin{tabular}{p{0.2\textwidth}p{0.3\textwidth}p{0.3\textwidth}p{0.2\textwidth}}
     \toprule
     \textbf{Version} & \textbf{Date} & \textbf{Modifications} & \textbf{Modified~by}\\
     \midrule
% we need to double the # here because we are inside a macro definition
     \xintFor* ##1 in \Revisions
     \do
         {\xintListWithSep{&}{##1}\\}% one row for each revision
     \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
}

\begin{document}

  \addrevision{0.1, 2017-11-27, Added new stuff, J. Bloggs}
  \addrevision{0.2, 2017-11-27, Added more new stuff, B. Smith}

  \RevisionHistory

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\xintListWithSep{&}{##1}` is a bit overkill: `##1` is simply for example `{0.1}{2017-11-27}{...}{...}` and we only need a macro `\newcommand\mymacro[4]{#1&#2&#3&#4}` in this specific case and usage will be `\mymacro##1` (no braces... we need `\mymacro` to see its four arguments...).

Answer (score 4):

You can let `\addrevision` write the table rows to a temporary file that you `\input` in `\makedeliverable`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
%%%%% In sty-file
\newwrite\RevisionFile
\immediate\openout\RevisionFile=\jobname.Revision.txt
\newcommand\addrevision[4]{%
  \immediate\write\RevisionFile{#1 & #2 & #3 & #4 \noexpand\\}  
}
\newcommand\makedeliverable{%
  \immediate\closeout\RevisionFile
  \begin{tabular}{p{0.2\textwidth}p{0.3\textwidth}p{0.3\textwidth}p{0.2\textwidth}}
    \toprule
    \textbf{Version} & \textbf{Date} & \textbf{Modifications} &     \textbf{Modified by}\\\midrule
    \input{\jobname.Revision.txt}
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
}
%%%%% End of sty-file
%%%%% Revisions
\addrevision{0.1}{2017-11-27}{Added new stuff}{J. Bloggs}
\addrevision{0.2}{2017-11-27}{Added more new stuff}{B. Smith}
%%%%%
\begin{document}
\makedeliverable

\end{document}
```

The file `<filename>.Revision.txt`is created as

```
0.1 & 2017-11-27 & Added new stuff & J. Bloggs \\
0.2 & 2017-11-27 & Added more new stuff & B. Smith \\
```

And the output:

[image]