# Create a universal table

Tags: tables

I have to make a lot of tables with same head, but different data.

So i want to create a template for creating a table with head, and to define a command to add row in table.

Is there any solutions to create that commands?

I have found a question related to [revisiontable](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/403361/creating-a-command-to-fill-a-template-table?rq=1&newreg=45e1894ece09471fb4e6c9b48011d644), maybe there is a command that clears the revision table, so that i can use that table a lot of times for creating tables.

Thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily define your own environment for that which starts a tabular and contains the head. To style each table you can employ packages like `cellprops` which allow content-layout-separation (here zebra-style as an example). To add rows you simply add them within an "instance" of your new environment.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{cellprops}
\newenvironment{mytab}{\begin{tabular}{lll}Head 1 & Head 2 & Head 3\\}{\end{tabular}}

\cellprops{
    tr:first-child {
        background-color: black;
        color: white;
    }
    tr:nth-child(odd) {
        background-color: black!5;
    }
    tr:nth-child(even) {
        background-color: black!12;
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{mytab}
    row & row & row\\
    row & row & row\\
    row & row & row\\
    row & row & row\\
    row & row & row\\
\end{mytab}
\vfill
\begin{mytab}
    row & row & row\\
    row & row & row\\
    row & row & row\\
    row & row & row\\
    row & row & row\\
    row & row & row\\
    row & row & row\\
    row & row & row\\
    row & row & row\\
    row & row & row\\
\end{mytab}
\vfill
\begin{mytab}
    row & row & row\\
    row & row & row\\
    row & row & row\\
    row & row & row\\
    row & row & row\\
\end{mytab}
\end{document}
```

Comment: what about a function to fill a row?
something like \addrow{\texttt{CustomerID} , Integer , *blank*  ,Use 0 as default value}
*blank* - can be empty cells

Comment: @ОрестЛегінович Well, you could do that with `\newcommand\addrow[3]{#1&#2&#3\\}` and use it as `\addrow{0.1}{2017-10-21}{add2}` within the environment. But I do not see a real use there. If you want to use comma-separated lists see the many examples on this site (although I believe that CSV input could be easier).